# Gooey (Python): How to clear text field after return_to_config

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I'm using Gooey to generate a UI for a simple CLI program that processes some text. The app works just fine, but I'd like to improve the user experience for repeated runs. The way the app is set up, a user enters a string into a single text field, and runs the app. After the app completes, it returns to the config screen.

Current behavior, the app returns to the config screen, but the user-entered text is still present.

Desired behavior, the app returns to the config screen, and the text field is blank.

1) does this feature already exist?
1a) if yes, where can I find it?
1b) if no, can anyone (maybe the library author?) point me in the direction of where the "return to config" action happens, so I can try and homebrew something myself?

Example:

```
from gooey import Gooey, Gooeyparser

def do_stuff(data_in):
    #do stuff
    data_out = data_in
    print data_out

@Gooey(return_to_config=True)
def main():
    parser = GooeyParser()
    parser.add_argument("TextStuff", help="This field doesn't clear after run")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    text_stuff = args.TextStuff
    do_stuff(text_stuff)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Have you tried `del text_stuff`?

Comment: Yeah, behave persists, unfortunately

Comment: I have the same issue, tried a few different things but couldn't get it to clear the fields. Even exiting and restarting a new instance of the program doesn't work since the 'running' part of the program will remain visible.